# How do I achieve this timeline with CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to create a timeline in WordPres like this:

[image]

I managed to create the vertical line in the middle of the content by using the following code:

```css
.here:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 40px dotted #44b072;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}

div {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center
}
```

```html
<div class="here"></div>
```

But how can I add the numbers on top of the vertical line, and how do I add the line at the left or right of the number. I thought of using pseudo elements to achieve that. But haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I would suggest to use svg for complicated graphics like these, but here is an example how I solved it with pure html/css.

```css
.timeline {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.timeline__backroad {
  background-color: #45B072;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
}

.timeline__backroad:before {
  content: '';
  border-left: 2px dotted white;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

.timeline__circle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #7D206A;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.timeline__circle.is--left:before {
  content: '';
  border: 2px solid #7D206A;
  width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
}

.timeline__circle.is--right:after {
  content: '';
  border: 2px solid #7D206A;
  width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="timeline__backroad"></div>
  <div class="timeline__circle is--left">5</div>
  <div class="timeline__circle is--right">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're amazing! Would have to look into using SVG as a solution as well, as you are right, the design already exists. No experience with using SVG in my Wordpress layout yet though.